# Is a auto body shop required to send me a copy of documents that they said I signed?

Tags: contract-law, fraud, deception

I requested through text message that they send me a copy of every document that I signed. They have not responded yet. In this situation, they have added $1300 of additional repair costs onto my original estimate. They never notified or called be before going on with these additional repairs. Nevada law states that any additional repairs over $100 need to be authorized. Do they legally have to provide me with the paperwork I signed? I’m intending on filing a complaint against their business for deceptive practices since they charged well above the written estimate and didn’t notify me.

Answer (score 2):

> Is a auto body shop required to send me a copy of documents that they said I signed?

During court proceedings there is a phase known as *discovery*. That is where parties obtain evidence, such as the paperwork you mention, that previously was unavailable due to an adversary or non-party being uncooperative.

Alternatively, the defendant would have the burden of proof that you authorized the additional charges. This is likelier the path to follow if you file the complaint in Small Claims Court, since there the proceedings are simplified or shorter than in trial court.